# Are there any security reservations involving PHP function getimagesize()?

Tags: php, getimagesize

I'll be using it in a modification for OSCommerce e-cart -- no user upload is allowed but SQL is for filenames.

Comment: Can't understand your question, do you want to know if there are any risks in using getimagesize() ?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to hit your memory limits quite quickly with huge or malformed images of certain types.  Whether this is a problem for you depends on how you are using it.  Also, keep in mind that if you use getimagesize() on a URL, you are doing an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no security risks in using it...you aren't getting input from user, and it just returns size of the image you pass.